# how to get binary data from sql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table containing some binary data.

I need to get the content of "select content from repository where documentuniqueid='1.3.6.1.4.1.21367.2010.1.2.166.155015116013230039.13086'" as a binary feed.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how it works directly within `psql`, but most programming languages will let you get binary data from blobs. It depends on the programming language. Which one are you using?

Comment: mmm... the simplest? I use Java. Isn't there any other way except to program something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Java, you'll find some documentation about handling BLOBs via JDBC in the [PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/binary-data/) (e.g. via an `InputStream`).

You may also be interested in this question: [Postgresql, JDBC, and streaming BLOBs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069541/postgresql-jdbc-and-streaming-blobs)

If you're not necessarily using Java, you may be interested in `lo_export()`, as @marto said.

Comment: ALTER TABLE repository ADD COLUMN "content" bytea; So stored as byte stream.

Comment: As the documentation says, you should be able to extract the data using either `ResultSet.getBytes(...)` or `ResultSet.getBinaryStream(...)`, depending on whether you want to read the result as a `byte[]` or an `InputStream` (however it was stored there in the first place doesn't really matter).

Answer (score 1):

Stored in a Blob I assume?

[lo_export()](http://www.postgresql.org/files/documentation/books/aw_pgsql/node96.html)

Comment: ALTER TABLE repository ADD COLUMN "content" bytea;